# How to use my custom principal when using JAAS in JBOSS

Tags: java, jboss

I'm implementing custom JAAS login module. In eclipse, I could add context.xml to /META-INF like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Context>
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm"
        appName="Bookstore"
        userClassNames="jaas.UserPrincipal"
        roleClassNames="jaas.RolePrincipal" />
</Context>
```

But in Jboss-EAP-7.5.0, it doesn't work. Although I have add the RolePrincipal to the subject in LoginModule, I still can't access protected resources.

I have spent much time searching the solutions, does someone know how to solve it? I will be waiting for the answer and respond soon.

Comment: I‘m implementing a web app for the purpose of login using JAAS. I'm sorry I forget telling it.

Comment: I doubt that recent JBoss versions use `context.xml` any more. The server's main configuration file (e.g. `standalone.xml`) and the vendor-specific deployment descriptors may enable you to do what you want (I'm not a JBoss user myself so don't take my word for it). Or you could use JASPIC, which would additionally allow you to significantly reduce (if not eliminate) the required configuration in the process.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have chosen UsernamePasswordLoginModule instead to implement JAAS. It's true that Jboss doesn't use `context.xml` and more. Although I have gotten another problem. Thank you again!